# Difference between expected spending and spending observed. What kind of statistical analysis should I apply?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, chi-squared-test, f-test

I would like some advice from you about what kind of statistical analysis I could do about that data.

My case is as follows: According to a research I have the information that the financial health of the company for a specific type of activity should put the following percentages on revenues:

Taxes 04.07%;
Feedstock 36.18%;
Employees 20.14%;
Buildings 4.62%;
Operating 27.12%;
Other 4.95%;
Profit 08.14%

Given the expected percentages on revenues, and according to the monthly revenue, I establish the values ​​expected for each month.

But during the year I have collected informations on each indicator (taxes, feedstock, employees etc) and observe that there is difference between the expected values ​​and the values ​​obseravdos.

In order to analyze whether the variation between the observed and expected is still within the expected range for a healthy company, I would like to apply a statistical test. But I'm wondering if it should be F-test or Chi Square Test (or any other test)

The other question is: Should I apply the test comparing which values? I mean, if I should compare the means for each indicator, or if I should compare the sum of each indicator or even if I should compare these amounts monthly.

How do I draw any conclusions about the data? Do I need to transform them into normal distribuition or any manipulation else?

[image: Expected_Values]

[image: Observed_Values]

Thank you!
Luis P.